# How to design a Model in ASP.NET Web API

Tags: asp.net, model, asp.net-web-api

In ASP.NET Web API:

1. The simply Model class code sample like:

   ```
   public class Member
   {
     public int id { get; set; }
     public string name { get; set; }
   }
   ```
2. We can easy to wrote the Controller code to generate member data like:

   ```
   public Member getMember() {
     Member oMember = new Member {id: "A0001", name: "john"};
     return oMember;
   }
   ```
3. When client AJAX send GET action, Controller will resopnse Member object data in XML (or JSON) like:

   ```
   <Member>
     <id>A0001</id>
     <name>john</name>
   </Member>
   ```
4. My question is "How to" wrote the Model class code to let Controller auto-export complexity XML result like below:

   ```
   <Member>
     <name>john</name>
     <data>
       <id type="A">id1</id>
       <id type="B">id2</id>
     </data>
     <wallet>
       <item type="US">Dollar1</item>
       <item type="RMB">Dollar2</item>
     </wallet>
   </Member>
   ```
5. Plz give me a Sample code of "Model class", or a HIT! Maybe I missed something, I'm a ASP.NET Web API Begineer!

Comment: Your question is not clear. You might want to look at serialization and using collections as well.

Comment: Hello, thanks for your suggestion. I have modify my question, Plz recheck my post, thank you!